# Getting OpenCV error : The kernel size must be odd and not larger than 31 in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, opencv, kotlin

Currently Im developing an Android application that allow user to either pick an image from gallery or camera capture, then convert it into bitmap, using OpenCV 3.4.3 library to evaluate its sharpness and return a score. I've been following [this](https://github.com/jainullas/ImageBlurDetection) for that. It was working, so I proceed to another function of my application, trying to connect mysql through web service. After finish that, when I test the sharpness function again, I get this error:

> I/System.out: ===================Getting sharpness===================
>   E/cv::error(): OpenCV(3.4.3) Error: One of arguments' values is out of range (The kernel size must be odd and not larger than 31) in void cv::getSobelKernels(cv::OutputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int, int, bool, int), file /build/3_4_pack-android/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/deriv.cpp, line 104
>   E/org.opencv.imgproc: imgproc::Laplacian_12() caught cv::Exception: OpenCV(3.4.3) /build/3_4_pack-android/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/deriv.cpp:104: error: (-211:One of arguments' values is out of range) The kernel size must be odd and not larger than 31 in function 'void cv::getSobelKernels(cv::OutputArray, cv::OutputArray, int, int, int, bool, int)'

By judging from the system output, I believe the application went wrong during the function below:

```
override fun getSharpnessScoreFromOpenCV(bitmap: Bitmap): Double {
    println("===================Getting sharpness===================")
    val destination = Mat()
    val matGray = Mat()
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bitmap, sourceMatImage)
    Imgproc.cvtColor(sourceMatImage, matGray, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    Imgproc.Laplacian(matGray, destination, 3)
    val median = MatOfDouble()
    val std = MatOfDouble()
    Core.meanStdDev(destination, median, std)
    println("===================Finish Sharpness, Returning data===================")
    return DecimalFormat("0.00").format(Math.pow(std.get(0, 0)[0], 2.0)).toDouble()
}
```

the `bitmap` is generated from somewhere else

```
var imageBitmap: Bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mCurrentPhotoPath)
```

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I've been searching internet and can't find any similar error at all. Any help is appreciate

UPDATE:-----------------

I actually recreated the whole project, and do it all over again step by step to see where went wrong, and found out that the error shows up after I add a new dependancies:

```
//Blurriness Detection
    implementation project(':openCVLibrary343.1')
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.6'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    //Volley PHP Request
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'

//Face Detection --- Error starts to show up after adding dependencies below
    implementation "org.bytedeco:javacv:1.4.1"
    implementation "org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets:opencv:3.4.1-1.4.1:android-arm"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.1.1'
```

Im not so sure is it because the clash between openCV and javaCV? And after this, even deleting the line couldn't resolve the problem, even though in Project Structure> Dependencies they are no longer there, guess I'll have to recreate whole thing again

Comment: It's strange -- you can see in the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/deriv.cpp) where the error is thrown, but it's not clear how it's getting to that state. Is there any more stacktrace available? Also, have you tried rolling back your mysql changes to determine what change caused the fault?

Comment: @greeble31 Hello, I've updated my question. I would like to know is there a way to restore that error without having to recreate the whole thing.

Comment: "even deleting the line couldn't resolve the problem" that doesn't sound right, I think it's more likely you made a mistake while trying to bracket the change that caused the problem. The Android build system is pretty reliable; if you remove some dependencies, there should not be any lingering effects. I think your best bet is to try again. You should be able to reach a state where reverting the last change you made causes a change in the bug manifestation.

Comment: Also, are you sure the input to the program is the same each time? Are you using the exact same image, for each test run?

Comment: @greeble31 Thanks to the backup I was able to recreate it again and test it again. Yes, the issue appear RIGHT AFTER I add dependencies on the library I mentioned. After that I tried to delete those dependencies, no, it didn't resolve the error. Guess its another delete and extract from backup. Yes, Im sure that I give same input to program everytime, Im using same image, and i've tried camera capture as well, not working.

Comment: And if you do a Build->Clean, after deleting the lines?

Comment: @greeble31 Yes, I've cleaned it and build it again. The error still persist.

Comment: Then I guess the question becomes, how much of the _backup_ do you have to restore before the error disappears? That is to say, in some sense, restoring the backup ought to be equivalent to reverting the source file. I wonder what the difference is...

Comment: The backup I have is right before adding the dependencies, restoring it and the app will run no problem with proper sharpness output, after adding the dependencies, the application go wild and the OpenCV error will appear.

Comment: You shouldn't try to load 2 versions of OpenCV in memory, yes. JavaCV comes with both APIs, so you do not need to add any other dependencies.